# fgoalattain gives cryptic message in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use fgoalattain in MATLAB toolbox to optimize a problem I am having. We have two concurrent filters that give us back a narrower range for the particular RGB photo we are inspecting. The function that describes this is:

```
function [ F ] = mycfafilter( greenwidth,redwidth,bluewidth,bstart,gstart,rstart )
...
F(1)= InR/InOutR;
F(2)= InB/InOutB;
F(3)= InG/InOutG;
end
```

These are percents always less than 1. So we set up goal attain as follows:

```
[F] = fgoalattain(@(x,y,z,w,a,b)mycfafilter( greenwidth,redwidth,bluewidth,bstart,gstart,rstart ),...
[10 10 10 450 550 650],[1 1 1],[2 1 1])
```

And run the morsel of code. However, we get:

Local minimum possible. Constraints satisfied.

fgoalattain stopped because the size of the current search direction is less than
twice the default value of the step size tolerance and constraints are 
satisfied to within the default value of the constraint tolerance.

This is a very strange error, or at least not one that I understand. The problem can be optimized from this particular start point, that I know.

Any help on the subject will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't sound like an error. That sounds like a success message.

Comment: But it doesn't run any iterations so it just gives me back my initial values, so I am thinking something is slightly wrong in the way I have thought of this.

Comment: Maybe you should explain that in the question. Are you sure you're not starting from an optimal configuration?

Comment: Well when I change the initial component [10 10 10 300 400 500], it still does not run though

Comment: OK, your code snippet above suggests that you're passing a constant function to `fgoalattain`. Are you familiar with how anonymous functions work? If not, you should learn:)

Comment: Ah ok sorry about that

Comment: I really appreciate the help though!

Comment: No worries:) It's easy to miss things like this, another pair of eyes often helps. But if your issue is solved, I suggest that your delete your question, since it is unlikely to help future readers:)